# htacess get the parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am planning to create a channel like YouTube. So I want to extract the channel id and pass to MySQL using PHP. Can any one help me how to get the value (hope URL will remain same while redirect).

Here is the link: `http://example.com/channel/UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0`

Output page: `example.com/channel/channelHome?channelid=UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0`

`$channelid = "UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0"`

(but the URL to public remain same like below)

`http://example.com/channel/UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0`

I tried below code but did not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ /channel/?($1) 
RewriteRule ^ /channel/channelHome.php?channeid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close! You can use the following to convert the id to a query parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^channel/(.*) channel/channelHome.php?channelid=$1 [L]
```

---

This will keep the URL on the frontend:

```
http://example.com/channel/UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0
```

But allow you to access `$_GET['channelid']` on the backend:

```
http://example.com/channel/channelHome.php?channelid=UCIIIKudjRlpV9mdh9YOs0
```

on the server side.

---

You can test it in action here: [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=67af2791-6c9a-51ac-8ec0-16ec3e9626ac)

Comment: As it stands, this directive will create a rewrite loop since the regex `^channel/(.*)` also matches the rewritten URL. You could fix this by just making the regex more restrictive (although knowing the precise format of the `channelid` would help with this).

Comment: @MrWhite To my knowledge, it actually doesn't, it works as expected. I understand your thinking, and I don't know about Apache at a low level. But this definitely doesn't cause any obvious rewrite loop when actually applied into a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an _endless_ rewrite loop. But there is still a _second_ undesirable rewrite to `/channel/channelHome.php?channelid=channelHome.php` (the desired `channelid` is lost). You could use the `END` flag instead of `L` on Apache 2.4+ to stop all processing after the first rewrite. (Although restricting the regex is still advisable, as I'm sure the `channelid` can't literally be _anything_.) "when actually applied into a `.htaccess` file." - If this was used in a _server_ or _vhost_ context (adjusting the URL-path as necessary) then it would work as intended with the `L` flag.